# OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long

Tags: rdiff-backup

I'm using rdiff-backup since a long time to pull backups over SSH to the backup-server. Recently rdiff-backup crashed with *Errno 36*. So I deleted the file which had the long name in the *source*. However, I can't get rdiff-backup to work again. I keep getting the following notice:

> Previous backup seems to have failed, regressing destination now.
>   Regressing to Tue Sep 11 02:07:50 2012 
>   Exception '[Errno 36] File name too long: '....

The file name pointed out here is in the *destination*. I've checked the path, and there is no such file. So, the file is not in the source, nor in the destination, but I keep getting this error. 
I though it might be possible to get completely rid of the last failed backup info, to start from the last working one. That is actually what rdiff-backup is saying. But it keeps on falling over this file which does not exist anymore.

Any ideas?

Is there a database where it gets the info about this file from, and where I can remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. If found the cause of the problem: eCryptFS. The backup destination was located in my encrypted home directory. And obviously long file names are a problem. After moving the destination to an unencrypted folder outside my home, it works. For reference: the system is running Lucid Lynx, server edition, all updates installed.

Comment: Note that lucid is now 2.5 years old.  You should upgrade to 12.04 LTS.

Comment: @psusi Lucid is still supported (even on the desktop), through most of next month. So yes, Andre should upgrade, but there is no immediate rush to do so.